# Laravel not autoloading class

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.6 and have created a custom directory for my repositories which is followed as

```
App/Http/Repositoiries
```

And all the files inside these directory have namespace as

```
namespace App\Http\Repositories
```

In my composer.json i have tried following of the two ways:

```
"psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Repositories\\":"app/Http/Repositories"
    }
```

Second :

```
"classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories",
        "app/Http/Repositories"
    ],
```

At any given instance only one of them was present in composer.json file and every time i changed the composer.json i executed following commands

```
composer update
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

But even doing so didnt fix the problem it always throw Reflection Class Execption stating as

**Class UserRepository doesnt exist.**

Now what i am really trying to achieve here is bit different than traditional way. I am not actually creating my class instance but rather i am using laravel **Container** class to **make** my repository like this

```
return app()->make('UserRepository');
```

But when i provide the namespace path to make method it perfectly creates my repository like this

```
return app()->make('App\Http\Repositories\UserRepository');
```

What can i do to fix the problem ?

Comment: I don't see a problem here. You have to use qualified names.

Comment: @revo cant i directly pass class name as parameter to make method is that what you are saying ?

Comment: Isn't it the need for namespaces? What if another class with the same name exists in your project? Read about Laravel [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container).